# Should I virtualize my PC or otherwise automate my PC install?

Tags: virtualbox, installation, automation, netbios

As I went through a new install/setup of my PC (typically Ubuntu), I wondered if there is an easier way.

I should explain.  First, at work, I work on what I think is a Citrix system. Not sure exactly how that works, but it seems like my work computer is more a host to a kind of networked image that gets updated/downloaded. If so, it's cool, and we should be able to emulate that.

Even if I don't have it right, on my servers I can deploy a system with Capistrano.  Capistrano would work for this too, but it's not really setup with that notion in mind. In particular, it's a "push" more than a "pull".  I've not used Chef or Puppet, but I assume they are similar.

I think virtualization may be the answer, but not sure. Or if I could find a kind of customizable net install, that would work too.

To elaborate, two things come to mind: 1) Setting up my laptop with the OS I normally use as a virtual machine, in which case, I'd try to set it up to boot to a "virtualizer" (can't remember the proper term of art) which in turn would download (if it wasn't present) and then boot that I stored somewhere. So maybe a very light install of a "virtualizer" and then a wget for my image. Is anyone doing such? I would think you could so something like it with virtualbox or the others, but can it be more of less seamless, and how would the performance be like?

Second, is there a way to setup a net install that can be customized to install me as a user, apt-get my apps, and download/restore a backup.  Is that possible?

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more on the question "why" - typically a full image of your system as backup is sufficient to restore your PC.

Comment: I added more to my question per you comment. Maybe your "image it" is the answer, not sure.